# Set cookie not appearing in Axios and Fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, symfony

I am using my API endpoint for authentication and setting a http only cookie with Lexik JWT token in the response when testing it with postman everything works fine the cookie gets set properly thing to note is that CORS is enabled with Nelmio Cors Bundle.

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: true
        origin_regex: true
        allow_origin: ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        allow_headers: ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'X-Requested-With', 'X-HTTP-Method-Override', 'Content-Type', 'Accept']
        expose_headers: ['Link']
        max_age: 3600
```

Here is the **LexikEvents::AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS**

```
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Events as LexikEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Event\AuthenticationSuccessEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;

class LexikLoginSuccessSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            LexikEvents::AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS => ['onAuthenticationSuccess']
        ];
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(AuthenticationSuccessEvent $event)
    {
        /** @var Response $response */
        $response = $event->getResponse();

        $hourLater = (new \DateTime())->modify('+1hours');
        $cookie = new Cookie('jwt_token', $event->getData()['token'], $hourLater);
        $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
    }
}
```

And at last is the fetch and axios config

```
const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-cookies', {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'include',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: form.username,
        password: form.password,
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      }
    })
    .then( response => response.json()).then( json => console.log(json)).catch( error => console.log(error));

    Axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-cookies', {
      username: form.username,
      password: form.password,
    }, {
      withCredentials: true,
      maxRedirects: 0,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      }
    }).then(response => console.log(response)).catch( error => console.log(error));
  }
```

After firing the onSubmit function the response is indeed a JWT token but SET COOKIE header is not present and the cookies are not set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 3 hours of research in axios docs, reading plenty of similar questions suggesting different fixes and testing I finally came down to these things: 
 
Step 1:
**For AXIOS** make sure to set the withCredentials in config to true(you are probably missing it if not you're fine just go to next step)

```
config = { ...yourConfig, withCredentials: true }
Axios.post(url, data, config).then.....
```

Note that the maxRedirects is not required(code in question)
**For FETCH** make sure to set credentials in config to "include"(you are probably missing it if not you're fine just go to next step)

```
config = { ...yourConfig, credentials: "include"
fetch(url, config).then....
```

Step 2:
This is the fun part, is your server running on something else than localhost domain like a 127.0.0.1:8000 url? Here is the catch Google Chrome and browser based on chrome engine will block cookies from any port postfixed urls(I'm not sure about other browsers but just in case serve your backend on http://localhost - 127.0.0.1:80, use hosts file to map your url to a domain, use localtunnel / ngrok just in case your browser decides to complain about your backend url)
Now you should be all set to store your cross origin http only cookies from response no matter the backend language it should be pretty much the same after you enable CORS.